# Opencv color classifying on irregular objects

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to create an algorithm using python and OpenCV to classify a portion of cotton with some pre-defined tones of white. I'm new at computer vision and struggling to make it work.

I read the CIE L.A.B is the best color space because it isn't affected by hardware (like camera or monitor), so I think it's the best option to compare tones of white (please correct me if I wrong)

For the first time, I used some squared images of the white tones and calculated the alpha against the pre-determined tones of white to classify it according to the classification of whiteness. My problem started when I started to use a real cotton's image.

I applied a mask to filter the range of white tones I want to classify and get only the cotton on the image, but the rest of the image (what isn't caught by the mask) turns in black pixels, and those black pixels interferes on my color check.

I tried many things: ignore the black pixels, reshape the image (turn the cotton image to spread all the image's area) without any success. I tried also to calculate the center of the image or draw a square to get some area of cotton's image to cut and analyze just it,  but I realized I need all the cotton's surface to be analyzed.

**My question is, I would like to know if someone have an idea how to process the cotton image attached in this question (entirely) ignoring or removing the black pixels.**

here the resulting image of my script:

[result of a mask and the contour detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MKXw.png)

and above my script:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import argparse
import colour

def getContours(img):
    contours, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    contours_poly = [None]*len(contours)
    boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
    centers = [None]*len(contours)
    radius = [None]*len(contours)

    for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):

        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

        if area>30:
            contours_poly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 3, True)
            boundRect[i] = cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
            centers[i], radius[i] = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])

            # print(area)

            perc = 0

    
            cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255,255,255),3)
            peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            # approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*peri,True) #retorna os cantos da forma
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*peri,True) #retorna os cantos da forma
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            #cv2.rectangle(imgContour, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            #cv2.circle(imgContour, (int(centers[i][0]), int(centers[i][1])), int(radius[i]-(radius[i]*0.5)), (255,0,0), 2)
            pt1 = (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1]))
            pt2 = (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3]))

            # pt1 = (int(pt1[0] + pt1[0]*perc), int(pt1[1] + pt1[1]*perc))
            # pt2 = (int(pt2[0] - pt2[0]*perc), int(pt2[1] - pt2[1]*perc))

            # compute the center of the contour
            M = cv2.moments(cnt)
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

            # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
            cv2.drawContours(imgContour, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            radius = int(area - (area*0.6))
            cv2.circle(imgContour, (cX, cY), radius, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            cv2.rectangle(imgContour, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 2)

#----------- Leitura dos parametros
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# colorPath = args["image"]

colorPath = './resources/amostras/algodao_in-natura_400x300.jpg'

# color_to_check_BGR = cv2.imread('./resources/color-samples/1x1_60-6-100.png')
# print(color_to_check_BGR)
# exit()

#----------- Cores pre-definidas
color_60_0_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[255, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_2_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[249, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_4_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[244, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_6_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[239, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_8_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[234, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_10_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[229, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_12_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[224, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_20_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[204, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
color_60_24_100_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array([[[193, 255, 255]]]).astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

colors = {
    "WB-60-0-100": color_60_0_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-2-100": color_60_2_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-4-100": color_60_4_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-6-100": color_60_6_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-8-100": color_60_8_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-10-100": color_60_10_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-12-100": color_60_12_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-20-100": color_60_20_100_LAB,
    "WB-60-24-100": color_60_24_100_LAB
}

#----------- leitura do arquivo imagem
image1_bgr = cv2.imread(colorPath)
image1_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image1_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

colorFound = {
    "colorName": '',
    "delta": -1
}

#----------- máscara para remover o fundo preto
# cria os arrays para serem usados como limite na máscara
h_min, h_max, s_min, s_max, v_min, v_max = [0, 179, 0, 255, 78, 255]
lowerLimit = np.array([h_min,s_min,v_min])
upperLimit = np.array([h_max,s_max,v_max])
mask = cv2.inRange(image1_HSV, lowerLimit, upperLimit)

imgResult_BGR = cv2.bitwise_and(image1_bgr, image1_bgr, mask=mask)

imgResult_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(imgResult_BGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

imgContour = imgResult_RGB.copy()

imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgResult_RGB, (7,7),1)
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgBlur, 50, 50) # pega os contornos da imagem
getContours(imgCanny)

cv2.imshow('contours', imgContour)
cv2.waitKey(0)

exit()

# cv2.imwrite('img_result.jpg', imgResult_BGR) 
# cv2.imshow('original',image1_bgr)
# cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
# cv2.imshow('imgLimpa', imgResult_BGR)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

image1_lab = cv2.cvtColor(imgResult_BGR.astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
# image1_lab = cv2.cvtColor(mx.astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

#----------- laço para procurar fazer o match por cor no array de cores pré-definidas
for key in colors:
    color = colors[key]
    delta_E_2000 = colour.delta_E(image1_lab, color, method='cie2000')
    delta = np.mean(delta_E_2000)

    if colorFound["delta"] == -1 or colorFound["delta"] > delta :
        colorFound["colorName"] = key
        colorFound["delta"] = delta


print('\n\nA imagem "{}" mais se assemelha da cor "{}" e o delta calculado foi de "{}"'.format(colorPath, colorFound["colorName"], colorFound["delta"]))
```

I'll be glad for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of using the CIE Lab color space is that color differences can be calculated using the Euclidean distance between both color vectors.

If you need to compare the color of each pixel, then do that and calculate the delta for each pixel that is not black.
A different approach maybe calculating the average color of your non-black pixels and calculate the delta using that average color.

It would help to have a sample of the raw original image and what is the expected output for a given image: is it a unique general color matching to one of the colors in your dictionary or local matches in specific areas of the image?

EDIT:
You can simply calculate the average on the pixels where intensity is not zero like this:

```
np.mean(img[img> 0])
```

You can do that for each layer in the LAB image:

```
mean_l = np.mean(lab[lab > 0][:, :, 0])
mean_a = np.mean(lab[lab > 0][:, :, 1])
mean_b = np.mean(lab[lab > 0][:, :, 2])
mean_color = np.array([mean_l, mean_a, mean_b])
```

Comment: Hello Carlos,
First of all, thank you for answering my question.

The image I've put on the question is the image after applying the mask to remove the background. As the cotton is a white thing I am using a piece of black fabric to help in the process of removing the background.
The problem starts when it removes the background, the opencv fills the removed pixels with [0,0,0] (it represents black pixel) and when I try to calculate the delta, the black pixels turn the image's color darker to the algorithm. I'm trying to find a way to analyse only the cotton (green area on the image).

Comment: I used the contours to identify the cotton with success (green area), but I don't know how to use only the pixels inside the contour area to pass it to the CIE LAB to get the correct delta only for the piece of cotton :(

Comment: How do you want to make the comparison? I would recommend getting the average color of the contour you have selected and compare that color with your references. I don't think comparing each pixel inside the contour adds any value. I would recommend calculating the median of each layer and use that vector to compare your colors.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you one possible way to calculate the average color in your images